# Build HTTP request based on constituent parts

Tags: http, go

Say I have a representation of an HTTP request broken down to parts like so: method, URI, query params, headers, body.

So I might have something like:

```
Method: POST
Headers: [Content-Type: application/json, Host: localhost:8080, etc...]
Path: /home/sweet
Query: name=dan&id=1
Body: "some JSON here"
```

How can I rebuild this into a valid net/http Request object? I would like to avoid string formatting and building as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

There's really only one way to create an `http.Request`, and that is with [`http.NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest).  And it already takes three of your constituent parts as arguments: Method, path, and body.

You'll need to assemble your query params into the URL before calling `NewRequest`. The [url](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url) package, and in particular, [url.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) may be of assistance with this.

Once you have the new request, you can add headers as you would expect:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/?foo=bar", body)
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

And in case it needs stating, the body must be an `io.Reader`, but that gives you complete flexibility.

Comment: I would have loved to avoid string building if possible. In your example I have to concatenate the host header with the path and add the scheme too.

Comment: The `url` package may help you with that. It can do the URL encoding/concatenation for you. Whether that's easier or not may depend on how you receive the query params.